# How to generate csv file in jmeter with unique name for every run time?

Tags: jmeter

I have a doubt.
I want to create "CVS file" with unique name in yy-mm-dd-time format for every run in JMeter.(multiple run) and send report via a mail.
How can i do this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: no, Because i have no idea to every run generate a  new file with date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jmeter results can be either generated in .csv or .jtl extensions.

Append the following Jmeter in-built Function to your preferred result file name.

**${__time(YMDHMS)}**

For Example: TestResult_${__time(YMDHMS)}.csv OR TestResult_${__time(YMDHMS)}.jtl

The result file will be generated as: TestResult_20160224-112120.csv OR TestResult_20160224-112120.jtl

[image]

Comment: Please explain what is a proper flow define a parameter to create a every run new file (${__time(YMDHMS)}0

Comment: If running on GUI mode, you must have been added a Listener to your Test Plan. Just browse/mention your complete path where to be saved your result file. Refer the image added.

Comment: can u explain How to send report via a mail this file.

Comment: hello Bajrang Badaik, I am done the create unique file name with help this command, but i am try to generate this report file name (testing_16-02-25-17-37-14) send via a mail.

my smtp sampler give the error :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\apache-jmeter-2.12\bin\testing_16-02-25-17-37-25.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)